# Customizing splitindex to reference sections

Tags: indexing

I'm compiling a catalog of documents. For creating the indices I have chosen splitindex, since the finished catalog will consist of at least six indices.

In the indices, I need to reference the call marks of these documents. Each call mark is assigned the section command. The splitindex documentation makes a suggestion on how to implement other references than the page number. I have used this solution in my MWE.

However, this solution is only designed to output the counter. What I need is the content of the of the section command. e.g. "Ernest Hemmingway, Ms. 3198"

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex

\newindex[Index of Authors]{IdxAu}

\newindex[Index of Texts]{IdxTxt}

\AtWriteToIndex{IdxAu}{\let\thepage\thesection}
\AtWriteToIndex{IdxTxt}{\let\thepage\thesection}

\begin{document}


\section*{Ms. 3198} 

Ernest Hemmingway\sindex[IdxAu]{Ernest Hemmingway}: A Farewell to Arms\sindex[IdxTxt]{A Farewell to Arms} 

\printindex*
\end{document}
```